# Reuse ViewPager fragment in Another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a heavy fragment which I don't want to recreate again. I have inflated it as the second element of ViewPager, now on opening a new activity I want to use that same fragment without recreating it from scratch.

**Thing I have Tried:**

```
 var fragment1 =
            fm.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager.toString() + ":1")
```

But the problem is this as soon as I leave my current activity which contains the ViewPager the findFragmentByTag starts getting null as ultimately I need this fragment in a new activity.

I even tried passing the same **supportFragmentManager** used to create ViewPager but then I started getting issues like Fragment needs to have the same container id.

Have anyone tried anything in this context?

Comment: if I understood you correctly: you want to pass existing already shown `Fragment` from one `Activity` to another, without destroying `Fragment`. well, thats impossible

Comment: Got it. Also, can you describe in little detail why this thing in impossible fundamentally, so that it could be helpful for future visitors? You can consider adding an answer.